# Javascript cookie for background color?

Tags: javascript, cookies, background-color

I want to maintain the selected color after the page is refreshed or closed and opened again. I've added three buttons to my page for changing background color.

```
<div id="color">
        <button id="blue" onclick="colorBlue()"></button>
        <button id="red" onclick="colorRed()"></button>
        <button id="green" onclick="colorGreen()"></button>
</div>
```

And functions in script file.

```
function colorBlue() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#002E5C';
}
function colorRed() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#BA1616';
}
function colorGreen() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#118E1B';
}
```

This is for a school project and it should be done using cookies. I tried to do it myself, but with no success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStorage for this. More info [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Set storage item with function:

```
localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'blue');
```

and then check when the page or whatever loads.

```
localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that i need to use cookies. It's for a school project and one of requirements is the usage of cookies. I'll edit that right away.

Comment: you can do exactly the same with sessionStorage or Cooikies. All information is on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie